# multiple definition of ... will not fit in region `ram'?

Tags: c++, class, arm

I am working on transforming an IMU library originally written for an AVR chip so that it will work for an ARM chip.  I've managed to get all of the macros and missing references fixed, but I keep running into the issue where it misreads the class definitions.

For example, the armcompiler gives me the error

> multiple definition of `MPU6050::setDMPConfig2(unsigned char)'elf section `.data' will not fit in region `ram' `

on the code below:

```
uint8_t MPU6050::getDMPConfig2() {

I2Cdev::readByte(devAddr, MPU6050_RA_DMP_CFG_2, buffer);
    return buffer[0];
}
void MPU6050::setDMPConfig2(uint8_t config) {
    I2Cdev::writeByte(devAddr, MPU6050_RA_DMP_CFG_2, config);
}
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you put that in a header file?

Comment: Running an `nm` equivalent and grepping for *setDMPConfig2* on all the object files would be helpful.  I take it the error comes when *linking*?